# Correctly using type-punning and erasure for array of objects

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, pointer-arithmetic, strict-aliasing, type-punning

My goal is to have a memory pool non-template class that is used to store arrays of objects.
The same memory pool object must be reusable for a different array (difference size, different type and/or alignement).

I already posted a series of questions but they might have been too focused on technicals details about a possible implementation, while this implementation might not be the correct one:

- [type-punning and strict aliasing rule for array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946075/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing-rule-for-array-of-objects)
- [type-punning: omitting placement new and destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946115/type-punning-omitting-placement-new-and-destructors)
- [type-punning with std::aligned_alloc for array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946148/type-punning-with-stdaligned-alloc-for-array-of-objects)

I will, with this question, focus on the "what".
I'd like to have a memory-pool class with this pseudo-code API (and an usage example):

```cpp
// type-punning reusable buffer for arrays
// holds a non-typed buffer (actually a char*) that can be used to store any
// types, according to user needs
struct Buffer {
    // start of storage address
    char* p = nullptr;

    // adding whatever method and variable required to make it work
    // ...

    // Creates an adequate storage (if needed) to store an array of N object of
    // type T and default-construct them returns a pointer to the first element
    // of this array
    template <typename T>
    T* DefaultAllocate(const size_t N);
    // Ends lifetime of the currently stored array of objects, if any, leaving
    // the storage reusable for another array of possibly different type and
    // size
    // Make it non-template if possible
    // Make it optional if possible (by calling it automatically in
    // DefaultAllocate if needed)
    template <typename T>
    void Deallocate() {}
    // Releasing all ressources (storage and objects)
    ~Buffer() {}
};

int main() {
    constexpr std::size_t N0 = 7;
    constexpr std::size_t N1 = 3;
    Buffer B;
    std::cout << "Test on SomeClass\n";
    SomeClass* psc = B.DefaultAllocate<SomeClass>(N0);
    psc[0] = somevalue0;
    *(psc + 1) = somevalue1;
    psc[2] = somevalue2;
    std::cout << psc[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << psc[1] << '\n';
    std::cout << *(psc + 2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Test on SomeOtherClass\n";
    // reallocating, possibly using existing storage, for a different type and
    // size
    SomeOtherClass* posc = B.DefaultAllocate<SomeOtherClass>(N1);
    std::cout << posc[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << posc[1] << '\n';
    std::cout << posc[2] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

[Editable version in compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ed9ss5Txc).

How should be implemented this class to avoid UB, memory leaks, to let pointer arithmetic be valid on the typed pointer (the one returned by ``DefaultAllocate```) and have proper alignment?

I'm expecting C++14 answers with technical references and explanations (what ensures the absence of UB, the validity of pointer arithmetic,...).

But I'm also interested in how to do that in more modern versions (especially as there has been some fundamental changes that lead to the need of `std::launder` in some specific situations).

NB In [type-punning with std::aligned_alloc for array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946148/type-punning-with-stdaligned-alloc-for-array-of-objects), a very interesting technics (using `std::function` and lambdas has been proposed in order to help data erasing).

Comment: Shouldn't `Buffer` just be an Allocator, and use/pass it in container such as `std::vector`?

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not sure. First I don't know how to implement a proper allocator, first my need is to pass around a non typed-buffer (actually, I should update my API to add a template function that returns the pointer (with or without type checking).
In some way,it can be seen as an ```any``` class, for arrays and with reusable storage.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly:

- You can only accept types that are `std::is_trivially_destructible`, if you want to clean the pool simply by deallocating the memory block.
- Ensuring correct alignment is trivial, that's left as an exercise to the reader.

---

##### Creating a single object

```cpp
T *MakeOne()
{
    return ::new(static_cast<void *>(address)) T{};
}
```

Adding `{}` makes it zero some types that would otherwise be uninitialized: scalars, and classes that have an implicitly generated default constructor, or a default constructor marked `=default` directly in the class body (for classes, only members that are otherwise uninitialized are zeroed).

Adding `::` and `static_cast<void *>(...)` makes sure this always picks the builtin placement-new, as opposed to some user-provided overload.

##### Creating an array in C++20

```cpp
T *MakeArray(std::size_t n)
{
    return ::new(static_cast<void *>(address)) T[n]{};
}
```

##### Creating an array before C++20

(the only compiler that required this workaround was MSVC, see [Microsoft C/C++ language conformance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170), and see [CWG2382 Array allocation overhead for non-allocating placement new](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2382.html))

```cpp
T *MakeArray(std::size_t n)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ::new(static_cast<void *>(address + i * sizeof(T))) T{};
    // Just remove `launder` if your language standard version doesn't have it.
    return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T *>(address));
}
```

[`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) is required when you have a pointer to a memory location containing an object, but the pointer was obtained in an illegal way (the standard says it "doesn't point to" your object, despite having the right value), such as when you didn't store the value returned by placement-new, and only know the pointer that was originally passed to it.

The lack of `std::launder` very rarely breaks things in practice (`std::vector` couldn't be implemented without UB before C++17 added `launder`, and nobody had issues with it). So if you're using C++14 or earlier, you can just omit it and things should work.

More UB could be hiding here, such as using `+` on a pointer to raw storage (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62329008/2752075)), but this is arguably a defect in the standard, and no compiler enforces this.

Comment: *"`std::vector` couldn't be implemented without UB before C++17"*. In fact, it is pointer arithmetic (`data()`) which (would) make `std::vector` UB (but as part of std library, rules are different). Without `std::launder`, we might have an extra array of pointer to store the pointer returned by placement new (inefficient but legal)...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat
1- I'm not sure how to properly get the right alignment (I will do through allocating an extra sizeof(T) bytes and computing an offset in order to fix any misalignment)
2- you're using placement new for each individual object but is it sufficient to guarantee that pointer arithmetic is valid. I thought that a proper array object is required and I don't know if a juxtaposition of objects is actually constituing an array in C++ sense.
3- why could I not destroy individually each object after usage for using non trivially destructible classes?
TBC...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat wouldn't it be UB to re-place objects of new types on top of the previous one without having properly ended there lifetime (through destruction for instance, see 3)? I'm far from being a grammar layer and the standard is very confusing for me with respect to type-punning, aliasing,...

Comment: @Oersted (1) *"allocating an extra sizeof(T) bytes and computing an offset"* You don't always need the whole `sizeof(T)`. Let's say `pos` is the current offset in the buffer. You compute `x` as `pos` rounded up to the next multiple of `alignas(T)`, and create the object at `x`. You then do `pos = x + sizeof(T)`.

Comment: @Oersted *"for each individual object but is it sufficient to guarantee that pointer arithmetic is valid"* It is not, but I don't think any compiler enforces that. But that would be for arithmetic on `T *`, while I'm doing arithmetic on `char *`, which should be even safer. I'm not sure what the standard has to say about it, but if it happens to be disallowed (the standard is full of broken wording on those details, see e.g. the last link in the answer), most people would agree that it's a wording defect that's not enforced.

Comment: @Oersted *"why could I not destroy individually each object after usage"* & *"wouldn't it be UB to re-place objects of new types on top of the previous one"* Objects are destroyed automatically when their storage is released or reused: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1.5 This doesn't call the destructors, so you're risking leaks if you accept a type that's not `is_trivially_destructible`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat about destruction: what would be wrong with https://godbolt.org/z/TePMTKdeo, line 86 => I'm destroying object but not storage?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat about alignment, if I indeed allocate storage as char[something], something needs only be sizeof(T)*N+alignof(T)? Is that what you're meaning?

Comment: @Oersted I think I misunderstood what you're doing. I though your goal is to accumulate objects of different types into the same buffer. But this looks like you're only storing one array (of a single type) at a time? Then I would just use `std::vector<T>`. If you don't want the class to be templated, store `unique_ptr<Base>` pointing to a templated `Derived<T>` which stores `vector<T>`.

Comment: @Oersted Note that `std::aligned_storage` is deprecated, and using it to allocate memory like this is an overkill anyway. I would allocate with `operator new(n)` and free with `operator delete(ptr)` (which are basically glorified `malloc` and `free`). They are [overloaded](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) to accept optional alignment parameter for types with alignment `> __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`. You need to store the alignment somewhere to pass to `operator delete`, or you can just reject types with alignment larger than that, to make your life easier.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, indeed, I want only one array at a time. But my goal would be to reuse the same storage for two different arrays (not simultaneously of course) as in the pseudo ```main``` above. Otherwise the solution with an erasing base wrapping an std::vector would probably be OK.
to sumup: getting storage, putting an array on it, using this array, ending this array lifetime, putting another array on same storage and so on...
I think its totally possible and well defined with single objects. For array, I've got perfectly working versions but I cannot rule them out of being UB (see links).

Comment: NB I proposed a [code on codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286755/reusable-storage-for-array-of-objects) that sums up many idea gathered in this question and the related ones.

Comment: I don't get why `operator new` with more bytes than the object is large would require a workaround? Why is that a problem and causes overhead? Also, why is it a valid workaround to write this for loop? That doesn't seem to solve anything.

Comment: @JanSchultke The issue I'm solving here is that array-`new` used to be allowed to consume more memory than `sizeof(T)*N` by adding arbitrary metadata at the beginning of the supplied memory block (which is complete nonsense, of course, and only MSVC did that). This made it effectively unusable, since one can't portably predict how much extra memory you need to allocate (and one wouldn't want to waste that memory in the first).

Answer (score -1):

You can create 'template class' and do something like this:

```
    [[nodiscard]] T* allocate(std::size_t n)  noexcept
    {
       
        if (auto p = static_cast<T*>malloc(n * sizeof(T))))
        {
            return p;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

  
    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n) noexcept
    {
        if( nullptr != p )
            free(p);
    }
```